# How to get values of a json array in php?

Tags: php, json

I have json like this:

```
{
    "Products": [
        {
            "_id": 1
            ....
        },
        {
            "_id": 2
            ....
        }
    ]
}
```

And got this json :

```
$str = file_get_contents($_FILES["uploadFile"]["tmp_name"]);
       // convert object => json
        $json = json_encode($str);
        // convert json => object
        $decoded = json_decode($json,true);
```

Now i want to see all `_id` of `Producs`.
I use this `echo $decoded[0]['_id'];` but it shows nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: try to print_r the result of json_decode.

Comment: yo can try $decoded['Products']['_id'] ????, but put the var_dump($str) please

Comment: print_r shows my json exactly but $decoded['Products']['_id'] shows nothing

Comment: and var_dump($decoded) ???

Comment: it shows my json again

Comment: please refer to my answer. your json has wrong format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$decoded = json_decode($json, true); 
echo $decoded['products'][0]['_id'];
```

This decodes the json as an array that you can use just like any other array in PHP, if you have trouble accessing values, then simply do a `print_r($decoded)` and that should show you its structure

If you want to loop over all the ids, then simply do a foreach loop

```
foreach($decoded as $inner_array) {
    foreach($inner_array as $products) {
        echo $products['_id'];
    }
}
```

[**Working demo**](http://3v4l.org/arjji)

Comment: @Saeed Did a little fix on the foreach loop

Comment: Thanks . i think this part of my code `$json = json_encode($str);` was extra an when i remove that and pass it works.

Answer (score 0):

You should be aware of using quotes on your json string :)
keys and values .
You don't need to encode it. the string is already in json format

```
$str= '{"Products": [{"_id": "1"},{"_id": "2"}]}';
$decoded = json_decode($str,true);

echo $decoded['Products'][0]['_id'];
```